# Problem inserting an enum value (Postgres + SQL Alchemy)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm having problems to insert a value as an enum value. This is my model:

```
class InvitationStatusEnum(enum.Enum):
    FAILED = 1
    SENT = 2
    RESENT = 3
    ACCEPTED = 4

class Invitations(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "tb_invitations"
    invitation_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    _from = db.Column("from", db.String, nullable=False)
    to = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    status = db.Column("status", db.Enum(*tuple(e.name for e in tuple(InvitationStatusEnum)), name="invitation_status_enum", create_type=False))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        self.invitation_id = kwargs["invitation_id"]
        self._from = kwargs["_from"],
        self.to = kwargs["to"],
        self.status = kwargs["status"],
        self.created_at = datetime.now()
```

The type is already created in Postgres as `invitation_status_enum`. Here I do the insert:

```
new_invitation = model.Invitations(
    invitation_id=1,
    _from=environ["CONCIL_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL"],
    to=to,
    status=model.InvitationStatusEnum.SENT.name
)

query = db.session.add(new_invitation)
print(query)
db.session.flush()
```

And I get the following error:

```
(builtins.LookupError) '('SENT',)' is not among the defined enum values. Enum name: invitation_status_enum. Possible values: FAILED, SENT, RESENT, ACCEPTED\n[SQL: INSERT INTO tb_invitations (invitation_id, \"from\", \"to\", status, created_at) VALUES (%(invitation_id)s, %(from)s, %(to)s, %(status)s, %(created_at)s)]\n[parameters: [{'status': ('SENT',), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 15, 10, 52, 6, 819247), 'to': ('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com',), 'invitation_id': 1, 'from': ('notificacao@xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com.br',)}]]
```

If the status is `model.InvitationStatusEnum.SENT` or `model.InvitationStatusEnum.SENT.value`, it doesn't matter, I get the same error. How do I insert as a value that postgres can accept?

Answer (score 2):

Solved, you won't believe it, but I was creating tuples accidentally:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):

    self.invitation_id = kwargs["invitation_id"]
    self._from = kwargs["_from"],
    self.to = kwargs["to"],
    self.status = kwargs["status"],
    self.created_at = datetime.now()
```

The commas were there, and I was thinking the tuples were related to SQL Alchemy. Anyway, it happens...

Comment: Thank you! I had the same issue because I was copy-pasting some model creation code and didn't think to look at the end of the line!